# Date Condition with Case when Holiday exclude

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need sales from start of month i.e 1 August till 16 August so this is my Query for sales -
Here Net_Amount Is column for sales figure,

```
select sum(case when Date=FORMAT(GetDate()-1, 'yyyy-MM-dd') 
                then Net_Amount else 0
           end) as TodaysSales
From SalesM
```

Now We have Friday Holiday , I want that if Friday comes then it should count from 1 August till 15 August i.e Thursday. I have one table Date Table there is one column Isweekend ='1' for Friday , How I can use this in my query as already I put one case
SalesM table has Month column and Date table also has month and year column.

```
select case when satrndd = FORMAT(GetDate()-1, 'yyyy-MM-dd' )
            then inna when IsWeekend='1' then 
           else 0
       end as Todaystotal


select case when satrndd = FORMAT(GetDate()-1, 'yyyy-MM-dd' )
            then inna
            when IsWeekend='1' then 
            else 0
       end as Todaystotal
```

Comment: You need a calendar table for this. There are plenty of examples on how to achieve your goal, many of them on SO. What did your searches on the matter (days between 2 dates excluding weekends/holidays) tell you, and what those did you not understand so that we can explain how they work to you?

Comment: On a different note, Incase no one has mentioned it to you: SQL Server 2008 is now completely out of support. It is suggested you look into upgrade paths as soon as you can.

Comment: Can you add some sample data with table structure and your expected output?

Comment: Output is I need Total sales as on Yesterday  so Yesterday was Holiday For us , if I Will use this query select 
sum(case when Date=FORMAT(GetDate()-1, 'yyyy-MM-dd') then Net_Amount else 0 end) as TodaysSales  Then this query give me zero result as yesterday was holiday so instead of holiday it should count 15 august as sales

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2008, there's no way you could be using `FORMAT`; it was introduced in 2012 (and best avoided anyway sir to its poor performance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I guess correctly, You are looking to avoid Friday if it is start or end date of your date range. If I expect you have two parameter of datetime type @start_date_param and @end_date_param, this folllowing logic should work-

```
CASE 
    WHEN DATENAME(weekday,@start_date_param) = 'Friday' 
        THEN DATEADD(DD,1,@start_date_param)
    ELSE @start_date_param
END StartDate,
CASE 
    WHEN DATENAME(weekday,@end_date_param) = 'Friday' 
        THEN DATEADD(DD,-1,@end_date_param)
    ELSE @end_date_param
END EndDate
```

Comment: I have start date and end date , actually I have output that one column sales as on yesterday i.e 16 August, in second column I am retrieving sales from 1 august to 16 August so second column sales is coming right but first column sale is calculating totally as on Yesterday's single day sales. so yesterday was holiday so sales coming zero but if yesterday holiday then it should count 15 august as sales

Comment: You can apply the given logic in your script. It should work.

Comment: can you post your query where you are trying to calculate that 2 values today's and up to today total? that will also help.

Answer (score 0):

Following case expression would work for the 2nd column (Sales_SOM_to_TillDate) that you are looking for:

It would consider "Yesterday" when not Friday, otherwise would be "Day before yesterday" you can add your own logic in case "day before yesterday" would not fits the needs

```
CASE WHEN satrndd BETWEEN 
        DATEFROMPARTS (DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE ()), DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE() ), 1 ) and  -- Start of the month
        IIF (DATENAME (WEEKDAY, GETDATE() ) = 'Friday', FORMAT(GetDate()-2, 'yyyy-MM-dd' ), FORMAT(GetDate()-1, 'yyyy-MM-dd' )) -- It would be "Yesterday" when not friday, otherwise would be "Day before yesterday" you can add your own logic in case "day before yesterday" would not fits the needs
    THEN Net_Amount 
    Else 0 END
```

If you want use your `Date` table that exists in your database, i believe, `Isweekend =1` should fall under `where` cause.